# Angular-cli Live Reload

Tags: angular, livereload

I tried to start an App from angular-cli(Angular 2), I can't figure out why I don't have any live reload.

I tried by installing npm live reload but it didn't work. In fact *.ts are not compiled so I guess it is normal.

How do I activate this functionality?

Comment: I just realize that I don't have live reload with this seed: https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed, Maybe I disabled all live reload by misfunction ? Have you an idea ? Thx

Comment: Your question is not bad but could be better if you read this [page first](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) : We need a bit of your configuration code to be sure your configuration is good.

Comment: Have you tried something like `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4201`?